# sorting rows with nested queries(querying on results of other query)

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have one table and want to sort the most relevant results with nested queries.
I have 4 columns `item_name, color, gender, pattern`  with 1 50 thousand rows

If I have given item name:shirt, color:white,   gender:female, pattern:solid
I want 10 most relevant results even if some attributes are not having exact matches based on priorities in attributes

need to get all rows that are matching item name
and then get all rows that are matching gender in above results
and then get all rows that are matching color in above results
and then get all rows that are matching pattern in above results

at last if results are less than 10 then we need to show remaining from previous query

I tried this with following

```
select product_type 
from product_feeds
WHERE color = 'black' 
AND color IN (select color 
              from product_feeds
              WHERE gender = 'female' 
              AND (gender) IN (SELECT gender 
                               FROM product_feeds
                               WHERE product_type = 'Jeans & Leggings'
                              )
              )
```

its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a prioritization list for the different columns.  You can handle this with `order by` on each column:

```
select pf.product_type
from product_feeds pf
order by (pf.product_type = 'Jeans & Leggings') desc,
         (pf.gender = 'female') desc,
         (pf.color = 'black') desc,
         (pf.patten = ?) desc
limit 10;
```

Comment: Gordon (God of SQL), If I understand it correctly, the DB might return less than 10 rows in any case. Then also, the user wants to return 10 rows by selecting irrelevant or unmatching rows from DB.